# Azure App Service returns a 403 error when making a self-request with a Private Endpoint from Front Door in place

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

## Init

I have deployed a solution to an Azure App Service where there is a requirement to run self-requests from the app service to itself. The app service is running with multiple instances, and I want to utilize the automatic TLS certificates from the Azure App Service. This means I am using the azurewebsites domain for communication from FrontDoor Premium to the Azure App service, for example, example-app1.azurewebsites.net. I am using FrontDoor Premium for this app service to utilize caching and a web application firewall for requests from the internet.

Issue number 1 is that the app service can't send HTTP requests to itself. Those requests end up with a 403.
[image]

Issue number 2 is that the app service can't receive HTTP communication from other app services. Those requests end up with a 403.
[image]

This article explains that the routing of the example-app1.azurewebsites.net is changed if it is integrated with a private endpoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-private-endpoint

## Question

I am looking for ways to enable communication from Issue#1 self-requests and Issue#2 app service to app service communication.

Is this possible at all? Are there any best practices for solving such an issue?

## What I have tested so far

Testing with private DNS and Network ACL, as well as host file entries, has been unsuccessful so far.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The HTTP 403 suggests that the request is making it to the service, but it's unauthorized.   What type of authentication are you using?   You mentioned "automatic TLS certificates" but I assume that's for SSL.

Comment: There is no specific authentication, and even if I set the network ACL to "public" or "allow all," this does not resolve the 403 error. This issue is due to the private endpoint modifying the target of the example-app1.azurewebsites.net domain.